# How to deploy a wp8 .xap from Windows 7

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have an xap file and have not access to Windows 8 right now.

I also have WP8 SDK iso file.

Is it possible to deploy this file from Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Because you require Windows 8 to setup WP8 SDK. Check this link http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=35471